# How to give a user read only rights for 2 Tables in the same DB in PGAdmin 4.23

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

I want to give an access to my postgres DB for a user so he can have a read only data for 2 tables in my DB.

So, I have created a role for this:

```
CREATE ROLE stagiaire WITH
  LOGIN
  NOSUPERUSER
  INHERIT
  NOCREATEDB
  NOCREATEROLE
  NOREPLICATION
  ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'xxx';
```

Then, I also create a user in the up right menu "Users", user type is "User", and gave him a password.

user: email@gmail.com
pass: mypass

Now, user can login, but he sees nothing, and have access to nothing.

How can I link the user email@gmail.com with role "stagiaire"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

User must login. He sees nothing.

He must add himself the Server, so he must know URL to connect.

in my case, my internal URL: `postgres.metadata.svc.cluster.local:5432`

Then, he will use his login / password to connect.

Now, he will be able to see all resource, but will only be able to open the one with access granted.

Hope this helps